# Codeigniter - Create Vote Up system in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to create vote up in my codeigniter named "like". I use this method, that i just found in http://www.technicalkeeda.com/codeigniter-tutorials/voting-system-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-codeigniter-framework

And update is run successfully on database, But the problem is the result of like in view is not showing and the output is text from localhost "Sorry unable to update". And when i refresh the page, the result of "like" showing up.

This is the **Controller**:

```
function voteme(){      
    $id_vote=  $this->input->post('id_vote');
    $upOrDown=  $this->input->post('upOrDown');
    $status ="false";
    $updateRecords = 0;     
    if($upOrDown=='upvote'){
        $updateRecords = $this->home_model->updateUpVote($id_vote);
    }
    if($updateRecords>0){
        $status = "true";
    }
    echo $status;
    $data['id_vote'] = $id_vote;
    redirect ('home',$data);
}
```

This is **Model**:

```
function updateUpVote($id_vote){
    $sql = "UPDATE vote set like = like+1 WHERE id_vote =?";
    $this->db->query($sql, array($id_vote));
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Here is the **view**:

```
<button class="btn btn-success voteme" id="3_upvote"><span id="<?php echo $data['id_vote']?>_upvote_result" ><?php echo $data['like']?></span> <b>Like</b></button>
```

This is **javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".voteme").click(function() {
        var id_vote = this.id;
        var upOrDown = id_vote.split('_'); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/ngelol/home/voteme",
            cache: false,               
            data:'id_vote='+upOrDown[0] + '&upOrDown=' +upOrDown[1],
            success: function(response){                
                try{
                    if(response=='true'){   
                        var newValue = parseInt($("#"+id_vote+'_result').text()) + 1;            
                        $("#"+id_vote+'_result').html(newValue);
                    }else{
                        alert('Sorry Unable to update..');
                    }
                }catch(e) {     
                    alert('Exception while request..');
                }       
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
         });
    });
});
```

How to get this result of like without refreshing page?

Many Thanks....

**Update**:

I have new problem guys, does anyone know how to redirect page in javascript.. I mean, to use vote we need to login first, then i replace
 `alert('Sorry Unable to update..');` 
with
 `url: "localhost/latihan/login";` but it didn't work... thanks for help before

Comment: Use instead of true/false 1/0 int

Comment: where should i put that code? controller? model? view?

Comment: Why you used redirect?

Comment: actually i don't know why... i just think it has to be redirect in home?

Comment: No need redirect because it is ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your controller function `voteme` after echoing `status` you should not use `redirect`, if you use redirect then it will return your home page html with `true` status.
So, you can use [is_ajax_request()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html), if ajax request is true then use `exit;` otherwise `redirect()` it like,

```
function voteme(){      
    $id_vote=  $this->input->post('id_vote');
    $upOrDown=  $this->input->post('upOrDown');
    $status ="false";
    $updateRecords = 0;     
    if($upOrDown=='upvote'){
        $updateRecords = $this->home_model->updateUpVote($id_vote);
    }
    if($updateRecords>0){
        $status = "true";
    }
    echo $status;
    // check for ajax request
    if(! $this->input->is_ajax_request()){ // if not ajax request
        $data['id_vote'] = $id_vote;
        redirect ('home',$data);// redirect it
    }
    exit;
}
```

Even your [referral link](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/voting-system-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-codeigniter-framework) is not using `redirect()`

Comment: I have new problem man, do you know how to redirect page in javascript.. I mean, to use vote we need to login first, then i replace `alert('Sorry Unable to update..');` with ` url: "http://localhost/ngelol/login" ` but it didn't work

Comment: use `location.href='your URL here';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function voteme(){      
   $id_vote=  $this->input->post('id_vote');
   $upOrDown=  $this->input->post('upOrDown');
   $status ="false";
   $updateRecords = 0;     
   if($upOrDown=='upvote'){
      $updateRecords = $this->home_model->updateUpVote($id_vote);
   }
  if($updateRecords>0){
     $status = "true";
  }
  return $status

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect with javascript, you can use 'window.location.href' :

```
window.location.href = "localhost/latihan/login";
```